# How can a directed cyclic graph have a "furthest node"?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I am new to algorithms and graphs. I am trying to solve a graph problem on an online website and The problem required to find the count of reachable nodes (which I think is countable using DFS) and the shortest path to the furthest node in a cyclic directed graph from a given source. I can't understand what is meant by the furthest node if the graph can be cyclic. What does it mean here?

Comment: For each node, it can be reached in ```x, x+l, x+(2*l) etc``` steps, where ```x``` is the minimum number of steps to reach that node and ```l``` is then length of the cycle. Now, you have to find the node with the maximum  ```x```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the graph is cyclic, a shortest path between nodes will never include the same node twice, as otherwise it evidently would not be the shortest. So the presence of cycles really is not that relevant.

Now when you look at all the nodes that can be reached from the source node (the "reachable nodes"), and the *shortest* paths from the source node to each of them, you'll have a *longest* among those shortest paths (or several, when they have the same longest length). Those longest paths lead to the "furthest nodes".